# Try to parse all functions with IdaPython

Tags: ida, idapython

Sometime Ida didn't parse some function into binary , so I search the beginning of function (in Arm it's `PUSH {R4-*,LR}`  and press `P` -create a function.

How can I do it automatically for all undefined function with IdaPython ? How can I run on all over "Instruction area" and try to parse function?

Answer (score 2):

I use this code snippet when I need to find, define, and do the auto-analysis of every function starting by a specific stub:

```
from idaapi import *
from ida_search import *
from ida_funcs import *

cnt = 0
my_pattern = '' # The hex value of the opcodes you are looking for

def is_function(start_addr):
   content = get_bytes(start_addr, 4, False).hex()
   if content == my_pattern:
      return True
   return False

addr = find_unknown(0, 1)
while addr != BADADDR
   is_valid = is_function(addr)
   if is_valid:
      add_func(addr)
      cnt += 1
   addr = find_unknown(addr, 1)

print('A total of ' + str(cnt) + ' new functions where defined')
```

In your, case, replace `my_pattern` by the opcodes of the pattern that you are looking for. For instance, in ARM, the "MOV R12, SP" instruction is a good indicator  of a new function, so I set `my_pattern = '0DC0A0E1'`

More details on this through this similar question: [How to know when a subroutine starts when reversing an ARM64 file?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28016/how-to-know-when-a-subroutine-starts-when-reversing-an-arm64-file/28018#28018)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the following IDAPython functions:

- [idautils.Heads](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idautils-module.html#Heads) for iterating over the segment
- [idc.MakeFunction](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#MakeFunction) for creating a function
- [idc.GetDisasm](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#GetDisasm) for getting the disassembly text of an instruction

Full documentation about IDAPython is [here](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)

Comment: The problem is that `idc.GetDisasm` works only if the address is code, so you need first convert the address to code with `idaap.create_insn` there is no function that try to convert data to code without make change into IDB